# Area of parametric curve

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, parametric

I have a parametric curve (shapes like a heart):

$r(t) = (16sin^3(t), 13cos(t) - 5cos(2t) - 2cos(3t) - cos(4t))$

$0\le t \le 2\pi$

And I'm going to find the area limited by the curve.

I have to find

$\int_0^{2\pi} y*x' dt$

$\int_0^{2\pi} (13cos(t) - 5cos(2t) - 2cos(3t) - cos(4t))48sin^2(t)cos(t) dt$, which is pretty ugly.

But I'm given a hint:

$\int_0^{2\pi} sin(nx)sin(mx) dx = \int_0^{2\pi} cos(nx)cos(mx) dx = \begin{cases}
\pi  & \text{for m = n} \\[2ex]
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

But I'dont know how to use this identity in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

In your ugly integral, Replace $ \; \sin^2(t) \; $ by $ \;(1-\cos^2(t)) $

and linearise by$$\cos^3(t)=\Bigl(\frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2}\Bigr)^3$$

to get $$\cos^3(t)=\frac 14\Bigl(\cos(3t)+3\cos(t)\Bigr)$$

then you can use $$\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(nt)\cos(mt)dt=\pi \; if \; m=n \; and \; 0 \; otherwise$$

Your area will be about
$$180\pi$$